# Debugging a thread dump from a java Grpc server?

Tags: java, multithreading, grpc

I’m debugging an issue on a java Grpc server where every n minutes, the server pauses when handling requests. I attached a profiler and I can see the issue straight away, every n minutes there is spike in the number of threads and then after a few seconds it returns to normal again and everything is fine for the next n minutes. I took a thread dump of the jvm when the thread spike occurs and I can easily see there are loads of waiting threads. But from there I can’t really tell what is causing this - see example output from the thread dump below. Its possible the server is just getting overloaded with too many requests, but I cant explain that from below:

```
"grpc-default-executor-1212" - Thread t@4520
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at java.base@11.0.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for <44b4dca3> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:462)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base@11.0.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

Has anyone encountered the above and can they explain the cause? 
(CPU usage and the Heap are fine so they are not causing the issue) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can check out the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) of SynchronousQueue

> A blocking queue in which each insert operation must wait for a
>   corresponding remove operation by another thread, and vice versa. A
>   synchronous queue does not have any internal capacity, not even a
>   capacity of one

You may use a SynchronousQueue as a parameter to create a ThreadPool.SynchronousQueue is a queue without capacity,when the threads from the threadpool to get some  task ,they are blocked until some tasks is submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I can see its SynchronousQueue that is causing all the threads to block, but its internal in the jvm/grpc code not in my code, so I can't tell from it what is actually causing the issue..

Comment: Though I'm starting to think the issue might purely be from running the grpc server on jdk11 (based on the output in the thread dump)...

Answer (score 0):

grpc-java uses a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` for callbacks by default. The cached thread pool creates new Threads immediately if no thread is available, instead of queuing a task. The implementation is a ThreadPoolExecutor which lets threads exit when they are unused (look for "Keep-alive times" in [its docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)).

What is probably happening is there is a burst of work that causes new threads to be created. Then there's a period of low activity which lets many of the threads stop. `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` uses a [one minute keepAliveTime](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#L180).

That doesn't explain where the burst is coming from. You can try specifying your own executor with `ServerBuilder.executor()` to debug, or just to specify a fixed-size thread-pool. You can use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` or `ForkJoinPool`. grpc-java team encourages specifying your own fixed-sized `executor()` when able. But that requires knowing your own application's threading needs.